# How to implement AES-512 algorithm?

Tags: javascript, aes

Is there javascript avaialable which implements AES-512 algorythm(i.e Encyption,Decryption)?
I found most of the javascripts implmented AES-128,AES-192,AES-256.

Comment: There is no AES-512. AES only comes in 128, 192 and 256 bit flavors.

Comment: Related from Crypto.SE: [Why we can't implement AES 512 key size?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20253/why-we-cant-implement-aes-512-key-size)

Answer (score 21):

The Rijdael cipher comes in 128, 160, 192, 224, and 256-bit variants.  The 128, 192, and 256-bit variants were selected for the Advanced Encryption Standard.  128-bit symmetric keys are considered to be roughly as strong as 1024-bit RSA keys, and 256-bit symmetric keys are considered to be roughly as strong as 2048-bit RSA keys.  In practice, nobody uses 192-bit AES, because they're either concerned about performance and/or export control, and use 128-bit, or paranoid, and use 256-bit.

There isn't a single 512-bit symmetric key cipher in common public use.  The whirlpool hash function, which is based on AES, returns a 512-bit digest, but that's not the same thing as a 512-bit AES cipher.

Comment: The common comparison with RSA is that a 128 bit symmetric key corresponds to about 3000 bit RSA.

Answer (score 9):

I understand that there is no such thing as a 512-bit AES.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_%28cipher%29):

> In cryptography, the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) is an encryption standard adopted by the U.S. government. The standard comprises three block ciphers, AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256, adopted from a larger collection originally published as Rijndael.

Comment: AES-512 is now finally entering the paper stage. Another year or so and it'll start appearing in programs possibly. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=6122835

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned double-AES-256 does not give 512 bits of security (rather 256+1 bits of time complexity) due to the time/space trade off given by the "meet-in-the-middle attack".

However I don't believe anyone has correctly answered "what" AES-512 actually would be IF it existed.  Note that all current AES variants have a fixed block size of 128 bits, therefore AES-512 if it existed would also have a block size of only 128 bits (assuming the pattern held), and thus would require NO CHANGES to the MixColumns or ShiftRows subroutines.

Extending the AES system to use 512 bit key sizes is technically supported by the AES standard, IF you allow `N_k>8`.  Note that the AES standard FIPS-197 has a design that is mostly independent of the key size.  The only thing that is missing is the number of rounds for `N_k=16` (`512 bit keys=16*'32 bit words'`).  The [current standard](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.197.pdf) (on page 14) specifies `N_r={10,12,14}` rounds for `N_k={4,6,8}` respectively.  Following the pattern shows `N_r=N_k+6`.  Therefore `N_r=22` if `N_k=16`...  after defining `N_r=22` for `N_k=16` nothing else needs to change, just pre-populate the first 512 bits of the key schedule (as specified in section 5.2) with the given key and continue with the algorithm...

the only limiting factor might be the Rcon[i] word that gets multiplied by `x (mod x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)` for every `N_k` words as it has a period of 51 and then begins to repeat. `x^51=(1 mod x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)`... however the largest `Rcon[i]` that gets used is

```
i=(N_r+1)*N_b/N_k  ; ((N_r+1)*N_b is the total size (in 4 octet words) of the key schedule)
i=(N_k+6+1)*N_b/N_k
i=(N_k+7)*4/N_k
i=4+28/N_k ; (correct... ignoring rounding issues (and probably an off by one error due to laziness))
```

so it's not an issue as less Rcon's get used as the key size increases...

Answer (score 2):

Please note that running AES256 twice is not equivalent in any way to a (future) AES512 encryption.

Comsider:
2^256 + 2^256 < 2^512

In other words, the time required to brute force 2 256-bit keys is significantly less than the time to brute force a single 512-bit key.

(Not that either attack is feasible on current hardware anyways)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it might be possible to extend A.E.S but the fly in the ointment so to speak is the shift and reverse shift values otherwise there should be no problems.
So for 512 you would need four rows and 16 columns but you would need to work out the shift factors as I said earlier. for 1024 you just double the number of columns but again the shifts and reverse shifts need to be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can go with an 8 rows of 64 bit numbers so that every row holds one 64 bit number and you can carry out the key addition on that without much trouble.

The left/right shift is not problematic as you can use write a 64bit version of *int64_t __lrotl(int64_t,int)* and *int64_t __lrotr(int64_t,int)*. The only fly in the ointment is the *void mixcolumns()* and *void invmixcolumns()* which have to change from %4 to %8 but I don't think that it would work but seems that it should work in theory.

Answer (score 0):

AES is just the standard and it deals with various things.
One of them is the cipher, which is called Rijndael.

It just is not available and defined with more than 256 bit.

You could theoretically extend this cipher to a longer key length, however 256 bit key length is already ridiculously strong for a symmetric key cipher.

Don't be confused by RSA keys and assymetric cryptography. They are much weaker and the equivalent strengh of a summetric cipher with the same key length is much, much stronger.
If you modify Rijndael you can make a lot mistakes that compromise your security. 
A 256 bit AES key is probably of compareable strengh as a 2048 bit rsa key

But what you can do, if you want to take your paranoia to a whole new level, just encrypt something and then encrypt it again. Encrypting two times effectively doubles the key size.
And you are still safe from making mistakes.

Comment: I suppose you meant "A 256 bit *AES* key is..."?

Answer (score -5):

There's no official standard for AES-512, however, you can easily simulate its effect by simply running AES-256 twice using two different 256-bit keys.

The main issue with running it twice is optimisation, though it may not especially affect Javascript since it won't be using hardware encryption support anyway. With this in mind the easiest method will be entirely dependent upon the library you choose, as most aren't designed with any kind of streaming functionality in mind, so you'll probably be doing two separate passes of the data for each 256-bit chunk of your "512-bit" key.

As others have queried though, the bigger question is why you would need true 512-bits of protection. 256-bit is still plenty for now, however, if you're concerned about it then the best thing to do is to design your system to accept variable length keys and simply run one pass for each 256-bit chunk; this way you can increase the size later by issuing/generating larger keys whenever you feel you need an upgrade.

Answer (score -11):

You can do it twice to have encryption add ups.

For an example, by encrypting with AES-256 two times, you would have 256 bits Powered by 2 therefore become 65536 bits encryption. ;) I doubt you would like the result of the performance on that though. 128 bits encryption twice would be 16,384 bits encryption though. You should only use one key for one encryption and if you want to encrypt two times, you gotta have 2 keys for two different encryption and I can promise you that it is going to be very hard for anyone to break through that kind of encryption. ;)

Comment: Encrypting twice with two 256-bit keys gives effective 512-bit encryption, not 256^2 bits.

Comment: Actually, it gives a strength level that is much less than 512 bits and much closer to 256 bits, due to something known as "the meet-in-the-middle attack".  There's a reason why cryptographers do not encourage people to try to invent their own cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: @D.W. You could chain them three times like in Triple DES.